# Error en NetBeans... The POM for au.org.ala:userdetails:jar:2.3.0-ogbrcoral-2.10 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: netbeans, maven

Buenos días al ejecutar mi projecto en Netbeans me tira el siguiente eror:

```
----Jar---
The POM for au.org.ala:userdetails:jar:2.3.0-ogbrcoral-2.10 is missing, no dependency information available
.
.
Failed to execute goal on project amr: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.portfoliorobles:amr:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: au.org.ala:userdetails:jar:2.3.0-ogbrcoral-2.10 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Mi codigo en pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.portfoliorobles</groupId>
    <artifactId>amr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>amr</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Significa que en las dependencias alguien está buscando a `userdetails` del groupId `au.org.ala` versión `2.3.0-ogbrcoral-2.10` y no puede encontrarlo

Comment: Si, lo vi. Gracias. Eh seguido el sitio que dice: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven 
y no veo que este userdetails en el mismo. El repositorio lo baje de la página dehttps://mvnrepository.com/
Si alguien me ayuda con la solución le estaría agredecido..

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Pude encontrar la solución eliminando la dependencia, compilo sin inconvenientes